# 2d java Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, java-2d, mouselistener

I am new to java 2d graphics and I have problem handling mouseclick event.
Is it possible for you to tell me why there is nothing going on after updating mouse status to clicked ?
What I want to do is to change the image in array at 0 2 to another image. Nothing happens tho. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements MouseListener  {

private static boolean[] keyboardState = new boolean[525];
private static boolean[] mouseState = new boolean[3];
private static Image[][] images;


Image house;
int w = 0;
int h = 0;

int xPos;
int yPos;
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("house.gif"));
    ImageIcon iii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("house1.gif"));

public Board() {
    house = ii.getImage();      
    h = house.getHeight(null);
    w = house.getWidth(null);
    images = new Image[10][10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            images[i][j] = house;
        }        
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            g2d.drawImage(images[i][j],w*i,h*j,null);                    
        }
    }
    //g2d.drawImage(house,15,15,null);
}

public void checkMouse()
{
    if(mouseState[0])
    {
        images[0][2] = iii.getImage();
        repaint();
        super.repaint();
    }
}   

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    mouseKeyStatus(e, true);
    checkMouse();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
    mouseKeyStatus(e, false);
    repaint();
}

public static boolean mouseButtonState(int button)
{
    return mouseState[button - 1];
}

private void mouseKeyStatus(MouseEvent e, boolean status)
{
    if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
        mouseState[0] = status;
    else if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2)
        mouseState[1] = status;
    else if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
        mouseState[2] = status;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register a `MouseListener` for your `Board` `JPanel` so that `mouseKeyStatus` can be called

```
addMouseListener(this);
```

Aside: Override `paintComponent` rather than `paint` when implementing custom painting in Swing and remember to invoke `super.paintComponent(g)`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work for me and also thanks for paintComponent hint, will check it for sure.